# How to create a Node.js stream server

Tags: node.js, http, stream

I am trying to create a server that sends out a stream of events.  I have created a Readable stream that I am trying to push to in response to key presses, so that I can control the stream of events to go out to the client.

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable
var rs = new Readable()

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    rs.pipe(res)
})
server.listen(8888)

keypress(process.stdin)
process.stdin.on('keypress', function (ch, key) {
    if( key && key.name === 'up' ) {
        rs.push('up key')
    }
}
```

When I press the up key, I get this:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^ Error: not implemented
    at Readable._read (_stream_readable.js:464:22)
    at Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:341:10)
    at maybeReadMore_ (_stream_readable.js:449:12)
    at _stream_readable.js:439:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I don't even know what events.js is.  It is not my code.

What I would hope to happen is that the string `up key` would be emitted out the server stream.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you pipe to the response, it will read from the input stream until it gets to the end of the stream and then it will finish the response.  HTTP is not, by itself, a streaming protocol.

Comment: I thought response is a Writable stream, isn't it? Are you suggesting that I need a Keep-Alive connection? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that what I really wanted was a chunked response, which does not pre-declare the Content-Length of the response.  This allows the node server to keep the connection open, writing to it periodically.

```
var streamResponse

var server = http.createServer(function(req, response) {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    response.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
    streamResponse = response
})

server.listen(44445)


setTimeout(function(){
    streamResponse.write('this is a chunk');
}, 5000)
```

I believe that Node uses chunked transfer by default, but the key piece is calling response.write() rather than response.send().  You can call response.end() when there is nothing more to send.

Note:  I may have some confusion in here between what is Node vs what is Express.  If you run into any problems, that may be a place to start.